# jquery mobile and json callback result not displayed

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I am building a jquery mobile app which allows the users to post and view topics via json.  the server side uses php and mysql injections to catch json data.  The server side does see the passed value and successfully injects it to sql.  The problem is it doesn't run the success callback result.

This error log shows on Chrome's console: `"XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://xxxxxxx/newpost.php. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."` And if I add `dataType: "jsonp"` in the parameters the error changes to `"Uncaught ReferenceError: SUCCESS is not defined."`

Here is my html:

```
<div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="content">
                <form id="newPostForm">
                    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                        <label for="postTitle"><strong>Post Title:</strong></label>
                        <input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" value=""  />

                        <label for="postContent"><strong>Post Content:</strong></label>
                        <textarea name="postContent" id="postContent"></textarea>

                        <fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
                            <div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#indexPage" id="cancel" data-role="button">Cancel</a></div>
                            <div class="ui-block-b"><button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button></div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <h3 id="notification"></h3>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the script:

```
function resetTextFields()
        {
            $("#postTitle").val("");
            $("#postContent").val("");
        }

        function onSuccess(data, status)
        {
            resetTextFields();
            // Notify the user the new post was saved
            $("#notification").fadeIn(2000);
            data = $.trim(data);
            if(data == "SUCCESS")
            {
                $("#notification").css("background-color", "#ffff00");
                $("#notification").text("The post was saved");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#notification").css("background-color", "#ff0000");
                $("#notification").text(data);
            }
            $("#notification").fadeOut(5000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function(){

                var formData = $("#newPostForm").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://xxxxxxxx/newpost.php",
                    cache: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: onSuccess
                });

                return false;
            });

            $("#cancel").click(function(){
                resetTextFields();
            });

            $("#refresh").click(function(){
                location.reload();
            });
        });
```

and here's the php code:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
    try
    {
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");
        mysql_select_db("dbtable", $connection);

        $postTitle = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[postTitle]);
        $postContent = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[postContent]);

        mysql_query("INSERT INTO weblogins (postTitle, postContent) VALUES ('$postTitle', '$postContent')");
        mysql_close($connection);
        echo "SUCCESS";
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

When the button is pressed, nothing happens on the client side, no notification but it does injects the submitted form to sql.

What have I missed? Thanks.

Comment: are you testing on chrome or its the same behaviour on anyother browser? try adding `www` to your url or try it without the `http` i.e. `/xxxxxxx/newpost.php`

Comment: I have done this but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

You cannot post / get using AJAX to a domain that is not the current one ....

Its call the same origin policy -> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

and when you added the following line

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

did you add the comma at the end ... ?

Comment: if it's a violation of the same origin policy, why is it that the injection is successful? this gives me an idea but am really confused.

Comment: @SaintShann did the inject happen when you had the JSONP setup ? that would make sense - the error was on the callback ... ie it was processed but couldnt execute the SUCCESS

Comment: @SaintShann and I think you need to add jsonpCallback -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/